# How to prevent QListWidget from shrinking when showing other widget?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I want a checkbox to toggle visibility of the label/button group below it.
Right now the listwidget shrinks, buttons below it move up and checkbox moves up.
What I want is the opposite: the listitem doesn't change size, the del/clear buttons don't move, and instead the big button at the bottom is moved down.

I've tried `setMinimumHeight()` or `setFixedHeight()` on the listwidget with various values.
Also tried putting the listwidget and delete/clear buttons in a layout and setting that height.
Tried to set Qt.AlignmentFlag to Top/bottom on listitem, checkbox, group, buttons etc. Noticed no change.
Found `SetColumnStretch` and `SetRowStretch`, but couldn't get that to work either.
It either moves less upwards, also moves downwards, or the delete/clear buttons move on top of the listwidget.

So, could someone please point me in the right direction to get the "Visible big button" in this example to move up/down as the group above it is hidden/shown, and not the listwidget and del/clear buttons? I want the layout to grow when window is resized (like it does now, that is), so I don't think I can use "Fixed" values really.
Here's a gif describing my problem:

[image: example gif]

This is my test code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QListWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QCheckBox,
    QWidget,
    QLabel
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        listwidget = QListWidget()
        del_btn = QPushButton(text="Delete item")
        clear_btn = QPushButton(text="Clear")
        checkbox = QCheckBox(text="Visibility toggle checkbox")
        hidden_label = QLabel(text="Hidden label")
        hidden_btn = QPushButton(text="Hidden button")
        visible_btn = QPushButton(text="Visible big button")

        group_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        group_layout.addWidget(hidden_label)
        group_layout.addWidget(hidden_btn)
        self.hidden_widget = QWidget()
        self.hidden_widget.setLayout(group_layout)

        main_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(listwidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(del_btn, 1, 0)
        main_layout.addWidget(clear_btn, 1, 1)
        main_layout.addWidget(checkbox, 2, 0)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.hidden_widget, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(visible_btn, 4, 0, 1, 2)

        listwidget.addItem("When clicking the checkbox toggle")
        listwidget.addItem("I want the hidden label\nand button to be visible")
        listwidget.addItem("But without the listbox height shrinking")
        listwidget.addItem("and the checkbox moving upward.")
        listwidget.addItem("The visible big button should\ninstead be moved downward.")
        listwidget.addItem("Possible?")

        checkbox.setChecked(True)

        self.hidden_widget.hide()

        visible_btn.setFixedHeight(50)
        visible_btn.setStyleSheet("font-size: 14pt;")

        checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkbox_toggled)

    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        self.hidden_widget.setHidden(not self.hidden_widget.isHidden())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

**Edit:**
As musicamante points out in the comments, what I really want is to increase the window size.
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760411/how-do-you-set-a-smaller-window-size-after-hiding-a-widget-in-pyqt5) and I changed my checkbox_toggled to this:

```py
def checkbox_toggled(self):
        state = not self.hidden_widget.isVisible()
        if state:  # toggle to visible = expand window
            self.hidden_widget.show()
            self.resize(self.width(), self.height() + 48)
        else:  # toggle to hidden = shrink window
            self.hidden_widget.hide()
            self.resize(self.width(), self.height() - 48)
```

and it works for me since I'm the only one who is going to use this so I know what not to do. The `48` can probably be set dynamically with something like self.hidden_widget.sizeHint.height() or similar. Off to experiment. :)

Thanks alot!

Comment: So, you practically want the window to increase its height in order to allow space for the previously hidden widgets? And what should happen when they are hidden again? Since you want the layout to grow, then what should happen, for instance, if the window is almost as tall as the screen height? Because in that case, the situation may be ambiguous: you may want to prevent increasing the height (or the window would go off screen), but then how could you know if the current height was set by a previous increase of the custom implementation or by the user when you have to hide it again?

Comment: No matter what you choose to do, any case would have an important flaw: if you always increase the size, the window would become partially invisible; if you only do that if there's enough space, then the window may be made smaller even when it shouldn't, or you may choose to not resize it, against user expectations. That's why such changes in window sizes are normally avoided in UX and are only considered acceptable for fixed size dialogs, which are usually small enough to avoid such inconsistencies.

Comment: @musicamante : Now that you mention it ... Didn't occur to me that I want the whole window to increase. Makes total sense that it doesn't work that way. I get your points about it being hard to achieve. But - seeing as I'm the only one to be using this GUI, could you show me a way to do it? Tried what I found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760411/how-do-you-set-a-smaller-window-size-after-hiding-a-widget-in-pyqt5) but when resizing the width of the window I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: 5 minutes goes fast. I don't need anything fancy, just increase by n when visible, decrease again when hidden. I'll play around, but if you could point me in the right direction that'd help.

Comment: @musicamante : solved it! Probably not in the best way but it works for me, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: It's not hard to achieve, there are a few valid methods (see my answer for a simple one), but the whole "resize the window when adding/removing widgets" concept must be thought carefully, considering important UX aspects such as window geometry (size/position) and intuitive expected behavior by the user. Besides the issue above about deciding when to actually shrink the window, consider other aspects; for instance, imagine if the window is placed exactly at the bottom of the screen: when the user clicks the checkbox, the size increase will make the bottom button go off screen, forcing them »

Comment: » to move the window in order to access it; and if the window was already over the screen boundary (with the checkbox exactly at its bottom), they will never know that a new widget has appeared unless they already used your program enough, or they decide to move the window up. That's why such behavior is normally discouraged, and other solutions are preferred: for instance, you can make the `hidden_widget` simply disabled by default, and enabled only when necessary. I know that this is just a personal program, but it's always important to keep in mind these aspects anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you have to adjust the height of the window so that it has enough space for the widget that is going to be shown, otherwise the layout will always try to use the current available space, possibly shrinking widgets that allow it: in your case, the list widget, which has a `sizeHint()` larger than its minimum allowed size (the `minimumSizeHint()`); all the other widgets have a `Fixed` vertical size policy, so if you didn't have the list widget, the window would have been enlarged automatically.

What you can do is to compute the space that would be required by the button and the layout spacing (since another item is being shown), and set the new height of the current geometry, then show the widget and set the *new* geometry.

Note that due to the complex way layout management works (especially for complex widgets like scroll areas), `setGeometry()` might need to be called twice, after processing currently pending events.

Finally, when you want to hide the widget back, follow the same procedure but *subtracting* the difference from the current height.

```py
    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            return

        height = self.hidden_widget.sizeHint().height() + self.layout().verticalSpacing()
        if self.hidden_widget.isVisible():
            geo = self.geometry()
            geo.setHeight(geo.height() - height)
            self.hidden_widget.hide()
            self.setGeometry(geo)
            # this is necessary as the size hints may not be fully updated yet
            QApplication.processEvents()
            if self.geometry() != geo:
                self.setGeometry(geo)
        else:
            geo = self.geometry()
            geo.setHeight(geo.height() + height)
            self.setGeometry(geo)
            self.hidden_widget.show()
```

I recommend to do some research about the primary elements used in layout managements:

- [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) returns the preferred size of a widget; for container widgets (having their own layouts), it normally returns the [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayoutitem.html#sizeHint) of their layout, computed using the `sizeHint()` of all items it manages;
- [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) is the minimum possible size, unless `setMinimum...()` functions are called with dimensions larger than 1; similarly to `sizeHint()`, by default it returns the [`minimumSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayoutitem.html#minimumSize) of the layout of a container widget;
- [`sizePolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) is queried by the layout managing the geometry of a child widget, so that it knows if and how that widget can be resized when the parent widget is smaller or bigger than the overall size hint;
- [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html) the object returned by `sizePolicy()` calls, instructing the layout about the resizing capabilities of each of its managed items;

<sup>Note that the `stateChanged` signal of QCheckBox should normally be used only when you're actually interested in the [`Qt.CheckState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#CheckState-enum), specifically for 3-state check boxes; if you only need to trigger a function based on the on/off check state, just use the standard [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal.</sup>

Comment: I actually ended up taking your advice and changed it to just be disabled and not hidden. Might as well learn correctly from the start. Will probably need some of the above for other things later on though. Thank you for the solution and all your pointers, even though it pushed me even further down the rabbit hole! :)